# Django - How to get debug info of DatabaseError "current transaction is aborted" in Django error page?

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-models, django-postgresql

While developing on my Django project I'm getting a DatabaseError that says:

> current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block

I know this happens because there was a bad PostgreSQL transaction without a rollback and the error in this bad transaction can be found in the PostgreSQL error log. However, I think it would be way more convienient if this error would be shown on the Django error page. Then you can directly see what's the problem.

So, is it possible to get these PostgreSQL errors on the Django error page? And if so, how?

Comment: Have you looked at the django debug toolbar? - https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/commits/master/

Comment: Did you do any research? Did you try anything? Did you check the Django documentation? Show your effort.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Yes. Did you know that this question is about a year old and has been answered already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to get down to the nitty-gritty details of the exception, then you can write a custom [middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) to wrap view processing and catch the unhandled `django.db.DatabaseError` and inspect the exception in a debug session from your development server's console:

```
from django.db import DatabaseError

class DatabaseErrorMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view, args, kwargs):
       try:
           view(request, *args, **kwargs)   
       except DatabaseError as err:
           import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
           # You can now fully inspect the `e` exception object and it's context
```

These exceptions are benign and usually occur whenever a thread's request-response flow prematurely ends, quite often during development if your client aborts the connection before the application could return a response, though that might not be all of it.